# Keeping a shared_ptr in scope

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a class that works on a bunch of shared pointers and stores them in various (**not** mutually exclusive) collections. One of the tasks of the class is to keep these containers up to date when it adds/removes one of these shared pointers.

To facilitate maintaining these collections, I have helper functions that classify a shared pointer, add/remove it from all its associated containers and do any other necessary work. This works well **except** that, if the remove function is called directly on elements of the containers, the shared pointers are free'ed before the function is finished.

I had solved this by passing the element to the function by value. This gives the function its own copy of the shared pointer and keeps it alive until the function ends. I was happy with this solution (and the need/motivation was commented) but this function keeps getting flagged/changed by code auditing tools (e.g., clang-tidy) as having poor performance and changed to a const reference.

How do I avoid this? The function is a small part of a bigger library and it is understandable that the maintainer is missing the comment. I am not in a position to change the code auditing rules so I would like a simple and efficient way to just avoid this problem? I suspect there may be something smart with C++11 and `std::move`?

An example, if my class was working with `FruitPtr` shared pointers, it may have collections such as,

```
std::vector<FruitPtr> greenFruit_;
std::vector<FruitPtr> redFruit_;
std::vector<FruitPtr> sweetFruit_;
std::vector<FruitPtr> sourFruit_;
```

etc.

The problematic function would then look like

```
removeFruit(FruitPtr oldFruit)
{
    // Remove the element from any containers it belongs to:
    if (/*Some container condition*/)
    {
        //Find and remove from container
    }
    // etc., for all containers

    // Do some final operations on the element that must occur after it is removed from the containers,
    oldFruit->markSpoiled();
}
```

**This works fine, but** if it is changed to `removeFruit(const FruitPtr& oldFruit)` then when called directly on elements of a container, e.g., `removeFruit(greenFruit_[i])`, the pointer `oldFruit` will be destroyed as soon as it is removed from all the containers, before the final operations are performed on the element itself. In my library these operations must be performed at the end of the function as they affect finding the element in the containers.

So, how do I make this function work with a const reference or make it clear to code auditing tools/readers that it cannot?

**EDIT**
Note:

- `FruitPtr` is a `std::shared_pointer<Fruit>`
- The only copies of the pointers may be in the containers that `removeFruit` is operating on (assume they are).

Comment: It seems that the `removeFruit` function really should share ownership of the "fruit", so you should not pass the argument by reference, constant or not. Is there a requirement that you must take a constant reference?

Comment: I would suggest `removeFruit(const FruitPtr& oldFruit)` to be a bad design. Why not just call `removeFruit(FruitPtr oldFruit)`, if you are already using shared pointers? Alternatively, you can use `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: Adjust or replace the `code auditing tools`.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have been clear.

Comment: @lisyarus my issue is that my original function DOES take it by value (i.e., is just FruitPtr), but I have found the function to be mistakenly changed by the maintainers of the library and I want to avoid this from happening in the future.

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't have the ability to adjust/replace the auditing tools, it is not my library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My immediate solution is to have the function make its own copy, e.g.,

```
removeFruit(const FruitPtr& oldFruit)
{
    FruitPtr fruitToRemove(oldFruit)

    //...

    // Use fruitToRemove everywhere in the function, e.g.,
    fruitToRemove->markSpoiled();
}
```

but is there something smarter? Like somehow `std::move` in C++11?

Comment: @Quentin, I'm sorry, but (1) your first comment is incorrect, this will just create a copy of the `shared_ptr` that will be deleted when the function exits, assuring that the object is not free'ed until at least then (and only then if it's the last copy). This is how `shared_ptr`s work, and (2) This is a valid answer, I am just looking for other/better ways to do so.

Comment: You're perfectly correct. I misread the parameter as `const Fruit&`, both my comments are thus irrelevant. Sorry for that !

Comment: As noted by @jvapen, `std::move` would not be possible when it is a const ref and do horrible things to the container if a non-const ref. I guess this is the best answer then? I will accept it when I can, but am still open to better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers ain't a solution for not having to worry about lifetime or pointers, they can, however, make simple cases much less complex.

Let me take the assumption that `FruitPtr` is a typedef/using for `std::shared_ptr<Fruit>`.

In that case, we can make the assumption that the only copy of this pointer is in your storage, because otherwise, you don't have a crash.

The easy solution would be to write the following:

```
void removeFruit(FruitPtr oldFruit);
```

By doing this, you will have a copy of the shared_ptr on the stack and the actual implementation will be cleaned up afterwards.

Assuming you don't want the copy of the shared_ptr, one could write the following:

```
void removeFruit(const FruitPtr &oldFruit) {
     FruitPtr tempStorage;
     switch (oldFruit.getType()){
         case Fruit::Type::Green: {
             auto itFind = std::find(begin(greenFruit_), end(greenFruit_), oldFruit);
             assert(itFind != end(greenFruit_));
             tempStorage = std::move(*itFind);
             greenFruit_.erase(itFind);
             break;
          }
          //...
     }
     // Some code
     tempStorage->markSpoiled();
} // Destroys instance if tempStorage.unique() == true.
```

Finally, one could wonder why you even the `markSpoiled` function.
This is most likely because other code is sharing the ownership while it actually shouldn't have it. In which case `std::weak_ptr` is what you need.

Whatever code still has some reference to the Fruit, will store `std::weak_ptr<Fruit>` and has to call `lock()` to get a shared_ptr. This pointer will be a `nullptr` if the last instance of this shared_ptr is deleted.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to say that `typedef std::shared_pointer<Fruit> FruitPtr` and that the only copies of the pointers are in the containers. Can you explain how `tempStorage = std::move(*itFind)` is different then just doing `FruitPtr tempStorage = oldFruit` at the very start?

Comment: In practice, there won't be much difference and I would recommend you way. Though what I wrote, is moving the shared_ptr instead of copying. Where you as a certain time have 2 instances refering to the same element, I only have 1 at a time.

Comment: No other code shares ownership of the `FruitPtr`, there are just member calls I need to make on it *after* it has been removed from all the containers. If `removeFruit` does not have its own copy (i.e., takes a const ref), then if the function is called directly on an element of the vector the pointer will null before the function is done.

Comment: Could you just do a `FruitPtr tempStorage(std::move(oldFruit))` at the start?

Comment: @Jon No, you can't do this because oldFruit is a const reference, so that would copy. Beside that, if the reference would not be const, moving it would result in adapting the vector, so you can't erase the element from the vector any more.

Comment: @Jon Note that I still believe that the 'by value' approach or your copy would be the 'cleanest' code of all proposed solutions. However, I guess that my remark at the is also important, as you kinda misusing shared_ptr for garbage collection instead of shared ownership.

Comment: Yes, I guess you could probably say my primary use of `shared_ptr`s is for their garbage collection... but I may have misspoke/forget my code re: shared ownership (sorry). In the actual code, `FruitPtr`s also hold both `weak` and `shared` pointers to other `FruitPtr`s, and removing `FruitPtr`s depend on these relationships. I look after all these connections properly without any ownership loops, but I do just allow `shared_ptr` to handle the garbage collection of being completely done with an object... I could probably do it all with raw pointers instead...

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists on two levels:  One is the technical level of writing code that implements the required ownership/lifetime semantics, and the other is a communication and management issue between you and the library maintainers - and it appears to make solving the first problem considerably harder.

There's not a lot I can suggest about solving the second problem other than talking to the maintainers and explaining patiently and diplomatically that their changes to your code change its semantics and need to be thought through and agreed between you.  While it's possible that they are just blindly applying suggestions generated by the audit tool, they may well have compelling reasons to insist on these changes.  Of course this is easy to for me to say, difficult for you to do.

A possible approach to the technical problem is to have `removeFruit()` return a copy of the input `FruitPtr` - this will keep the `Fruit` object alive until the caller decides what to do with it.

Comment: My preferred solution is to make the code as "easy-to-maintain" as possible. This both reduces the load on me and the maintainers looking after the library as a whole. Keeping the return value in scope would still require taking a copy of it, correct? Would there by any advantages of that over my base-line solution posted below?